# Square integrable function that doesn't go to zero?

Tags: functions, integration

I'm reading through some elementary quantum mechanics textbooks and a few authors mention that "there exist pathological functions that are square-integrable but do not go to zero at infinity." ([Griffiths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Griffiths_%28physicist%29))

I am having trouble coming up with one, does anybody have an example?

The only one I can think of is the [dirac distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132514/prove-that-the-integral-of-an-odd-step-function-on-1-1-is-0?rq=1) (which isn't even a function...):
[image]

Comment: Since integration ignores point discontinuities, the function $f(x)=1$ for $x$ integer and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$ provides a simple example.

Comment: This post looks somewhat related. http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=1781128

Comment: There are those that are continuous, even. Let $f$ have a graph consisting of an infinite number of spikes ("centered" on the integers, say) of height $1$ such that the widths of the spikes are small enough so that $f$ is in $L_2$.

Comment: Why do people consider these examples 'pathological'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the function:
$$
x^2\exp(−x^8 \sin^2 x)
$$

I found it in this article: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069.
More specifically on page 7.

Comment: I cleaned up the $\LaTeX$, and fixed a typo in the definition of the function ($\sin^2 x$ was incorrectly copied as $\sin(2x)$, resulting in a function that isn't $L^2$.)

Comment: Thanks mate! I gotta learn TeX!

Comment: There's a brief intro [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Do you know what the square integral is by any chance? Or the $L^2$ norm (norm squared) of the state I mean.

Answer (score 7):

As David and proximal have pointed out in the comments, there are many square-integrable functions which do not go to $0$ in the limit, even continuous ones. However, we do have the following:

> Suppose $f : \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ is uniformly continuous, and $f\in L^p$ for some $p\geq 1$. Then $|f(x)|\to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 7):

Along the lines of David Mitra's comment, try
$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{[n, n + 2^{-n}]}.$$
That is, $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is in one of the intervals $[1,1+1/2], [2, 2+1/4], [3, 3+1/8], \dots$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Clearly $f(x)$ does not approach 0 as $x \to \infty$, since for any $N$ there are $x \ge N$ with $f(x) = 1$ and other $x \ge N$ with $f(x) = 0$.  But on the other hand, it's easy to compute that $\int f^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$.

With a little more work you can make this function continuous, or even $C^\infty$.