# Does $e^{-\delta t}f(t)\to 0$ if $f \in L^2([0,+\infty))$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A function $f:[0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ in $L^2([0,+\infty))$ does *not* have to decay at infinity i.e. $f(t) \to 0$ as $t\to +\infty$, even if $f$ is continuous (a sufficient condition proposed in [Square integrable function that doesn't go to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384992/square-integrable-function-that-doesnt-go-to-zero) is that $f$ is uniformely continuous).

However, I wonder if multiplying by a function like a decaying exponential,  $f$ will decay too. More precisely:

> Let $\delta>0$, and $f \in L^2([0,+\infty)$ continuous, is it true that $e^{-\delta t}f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$?

(Note: I added the continuity hypothesis on $f$ because otherwise one could redefine $f$ on a $0$-measure subset of $[0,+\infty)$ to avoid convergence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{\delta n}$ on $[n, n+e^{-3\delta n}]$ for $n =1,2,...$ and $0$ elsewhere.  Then $f \in L^{2}$ and $e^{-\delta n}f(n) \to 1$. This is not continuous but you can modify it slightly to make it continuous.

[Consider small intervals to the left of $n$ and the right of $n+e^{-3\delta n}$ and bring the graph down to $0$].